# What is the preimage of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ under the reduction map $\mathbb{Q}[x]_{(x)}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be the localization of the integers at the prime ideal $(p)$.

Consider the natural reduction map $\pi : \mathbb{Q}[x]_{(x)}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ (sending $x\mapsto 0$).

The inverse image $\pi^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})$ is precisely the subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]_{(x)}$ which evaluate to an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ upon setting $x = 0$.

Is there a nice way to describe the preimage "in a formula"?

Here are some observations:

1. It contains $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]$.
2. It does not contain $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]_{(x)}$, since $1/p$ lies in that ring.
3. It strictly contains $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]_{(p,x)}$ - strictly because this is a noetherian local ring of dimension 2, but by various theorems the preimage is a valuation ring, but the only noetherian valuation rings are discrete valuation rings, which have dim 1.